# Azure speech-to-text ignores numbers

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm using azure speech to text to find timestamps of utterances in a wav file.

The problem I'm encountering is that if the user has recorded numbers, for instance "I'm going to count to three. One, two, three, here I come". The numbers are omitted from the output. This happens both for English and other languages.
I can understand utterances like 'eh' and 'ah' being omitted, but numbers? why is that the default.

I'm using:

- speechConfig.OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Detailed;
- the default language model.

Can I somehow configure the SpeechRecognizer differently so it also outputs numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason my results did not recognizing numbers. It was in my own code.
In my postprocessing I was trying to get rid of punctuation marks from the result. Here I was also accidently getting rid of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

- So, using the following code I was able to convert a `.wav`  audio file to text without the loss of data.

```
 string speechKey = "<Your_Key>";
 string speechRegion = "Your_Region";
 
 var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription(speechKey, speechRegion);
        
speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";

using var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput("<Path to File>");

using var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

        
var speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
       
Console.WriteLine(speechRecognitionResult.Text);
```

output:
[image]

- But apparently there is a bug in the conversion model where if there is a pause between`I'm going to count to three.` and `One, two, three, here I come` . The model will omit the `One, two, three, here I come` sentence from the audio file.
- Also, I couldn't find anything in this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.audio.audioconfig?view=azure-dotnet) on audio config class to configure the audio settings regarding this issue.

Comment: The 'bug' you are encountering is because you are using RecognizeOnceAsync. It only outputs the first 'utterance', so if there is a pause in the audio, it will quit reporting the words it could recognize after the pause. I found this very misleading as well.